# How do I use templateDefaults with templates in an argo workslows WorkflowTemplate

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I'd like to use the [templateDefaults](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/template-defaults/) feature to share common environment variables & images between a set of script templates defined in a WorkflowTemplate resource, something like this;

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
spec:
  templateDefaults:
      script:
         image: someimage:v1.2.3

  templates:
    - name: foo
      script:
        name: 'foo'
      ...
    - name: bar
      script:
        name: 'bar'
      ...
```

this does not work for me when i reference the template in another workflow - the `templateDefaults` seem to get ignored & i get an error that the script image is not defined.

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please also share the argo version you are using. I actually have the same problem with setting `templateDefaults` in the `workflow-controller-configmap` for ALL workflows and it does not work either. I'm using Argo 3.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this [Ticket](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/5842#issuecomment-833618341):

> templatedefault will not work in templateRef scenario. Because templateRef is just referring the template not the entire workflowSpec in workflowtemplate. you have to move the templateDefault to caller (Workflow) spec.